# Question disappearing from "active"

Tags: support

Today I noticed a question disappearing from the "active" list, though it didn't appear to be deleted; at least I still could access it with the question number in the URL, and it got another vote after it disappeared as well. Can anybody explain what happened here?

The question in question :-) is [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18732/lets-brainstorm-on-projects-ideas). I wanted to monitor it because of its downvotes and wanted to see if it got closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the 'active' list is used to mean https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active, the list found by clicking the Questions button/IC and the "active" tab.  I believe you're referring to the front page 'active' tab, located at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/?tab=active. They are completely different lists.

The question appears on the "active" list, but not the front page.  This is consistent with the behavior described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50988/146495):

> Also, the front page does not display negatively voted questions, provided that it has refreshed by the time that the question is negative. See voyager's comment on this post. A question that was just recently downvoted might still be on the front page, but by the next time the front page refreshes it should be gone.

This post received quite a few downvotes, so it should have disappeared from the front page.

Comment: Yes, I meant the front page. The downvotes explain it then, thanks.